# How to find unused files in a CMake C++ project

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a huge legacy code project that I want to clean up a little. I know for a fact a couple of files are not actually being used. The project is based on CMake. But there are more than 15 targets with lots of dynamic variables containing source file paths, so reading the `CMakeLists.txt` manually is tricky.

So can I produce a list of unused files automatically after a CMake build?
We should be able to get a list of the *used* `.cpp` source files after the build, and I bet we can deduct this from an e.g. `find ...` command.

Note: here I refer to unused files as source files that aren't compiled into a target. Ideally I would also want the unused `.h` header files, but I bet that's outside the CMake scope.

Comment: Some files might be included only in some conditions (platform/options/...) (or used in custom action) I don't think there is something automatic.

Comment: You could ask CMake to create [compile_commands.json](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) file. This file has references to all source files which are **compiled**. Note, that, as previous commenter said, set of the compiled source files may **depend on configuration**.

Comment: Maybe a dumb idea, but have you considered trying to just eyeball things that look like they're not being used, deleting them one by one, and just trying to build and seeing if the build fails? Separate idea: For a shared library with explicit visibility specifiers or an executable, you could probably get mileage out of static analysis tools to find unused code. I'm not sure about static libraries.